# Wagtail, can't add settings

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-cms

I'm trying to add custom settings to wagtail (version 4.0.4).

Following the guide from the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.0.4/reference/contrib/settings.html), I added `wagtail.contrib.settings` to INSTALLED_APPS and added this to *models.py*:

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import register_setting, BaseGenericSetting
from django.db import models


@register_setting
class Authors(BaseGenericSetting):
    facebook = models.URLField()
```

Then made makemigrations/migrate. But nothing appeared in Wagtail settings.

Then I tried to register model in admin. In wagtail_admin.py

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin,
    modeladmin_register,
)
from .models import Authors


@modeladmin_register
class AuthorsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Authors
    list_display = ("facebook",)
    add_to_settings_menu = True
    menu_label = "Authors"
```

But still the same result. What do I miss? Some extra config or ...?

Only after removing `add_to_settings_menu = True`, Authors appears in the side-menu (but, of course, not in the settings). With this line - nothing.

Comment: Since the first one is straight from the docs with a little renaming, it should work. Try stopping and starting your dev server and then look.

Comment: @cnk - Already did that. That's why I'm asking for help on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root problem. In my project, there was a custom

```
@hooks.register("construct_settings_menu")
def hide_settings_items(request, menu_items):
    menu_items[:] = [some_logic]
```

Which deleted items from settings menu

But I still have to do `@modeladmin_register`